# Why the key prefix optimization doesn't work with secondary index on a clustering column?

Tags: scylla

Scylla DB implements, so-called "[key prefix optimization](https://youtu.be/dyWZRjtPI2s?t=2508)" for secondary indexes, which eliminates filtering if a part of the primary key is specified. E.g. it's possible to execute `SELECT * FROM A WHERE a = 'a' AND b = 'a' AND d = 'a';` on table `A`.

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    a text,
    b text,
    c text,
    d text,
    PRIMARY KEY(a,b,c)
);
CREATE INDEX A_index ON A (d);
```

But it doesn't work if `A.d` is a clustering column. E.g. as in table `B` below.

```
CREATE TABLE B (
    a text,
    b text,
    c text,
    d text,
    PRIMARY KEY(a,b,c,d)
);
CREATE INDEX B_index ON B (d);
```

The above SELECT query fails with the error:

> InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query]
>   message="Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering
>   and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute
>   this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW
>   FILTERING"

ScyllaDB 3.0.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thanks for finding an interesting corner case :)

The problem is that the second query restricts clustering columns `(b, d)`, which in itself does not form a clustering key prefix. Of course, `d` is indexed, so what *should* happen is using `a` in key prefix optimization and `d` as an indexed column.

Instead, it's wrongfully decided that `(b, d)` does not form a prefix, so it's discarded from optimization candidates, without taking into account that `d` has an index.

This simplification will be fixed, I created a bug tracker issue here: https://github.com/scylladb/scylla/issues/4178